# Api request is returning a URL and not the data

Tags: jquery, api

With the api I am using to get the info for the 3rd LI it only returns me the url to the information . How would I actually access that information in that url in the same call?

```js
var $orders = $('#lukeData');
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: "https://swapi.co/api/people/1/",
  success: function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(i, order) {
      $orders.html('<ul><b>Sex:' + data.gender + '<br>' + data.birth_year + '<br>' + data.starships + '</b></ul>');
    });
  }
})
```

```css
#boxOne {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: url();
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: -400px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="boxOne" class="container">
  <h1>Luke SkyWalker</h1>
  <div id="lukeData"> Details</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code is working properly. The output of `data.starships` appears to be a URL because that's what's returned; an array of URL strings: `"starships": ["https://swapi.co/api/starships/12/", "https://swapi.co/api/starships/22/"]`. From the look of those endpoints, you will need to make extra AJAX requests to get the information about those starships.

Comment: One other thing to note is that your HTML is invalid - you can only place a `li` element within a `ul`

Comment: Change the output format by adding `?format=...`. Available options are `json`, `api` and `wookiee`

Comment: @Andreas what line would I add that to? I am new to learning api's

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to load a `person` and then get details of their `sharship(s)` - you need to make further API requests for each starship - such as below.

```js
var $orders = $('#lukeData');
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: "https://swapi.co/api/people/1/?format=json"
}).then(function(data){
  var html = '<b>Sex:' + data.gender + '<br>' + data.birth_year;
  
  $.when(...data.starships.map(function(ssUrl){
      return $.ajax({
         type:'get',
         url:ssUrl + "?format=json"
      })
  })).then(function(...starships){
      html += "<ul>";
      starships.forEach(function(ss){
          html += "<li>" + ss[0].name + "</li>";
      });
      html += "</ul>"
      $orders.html(html);
  });
});
```

```css
#boxOne {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: url();
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: -400px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="boxOne" class="container">
  <h1>Luke SkyWalker</h1>
  <div id="lukeData"> Details</div>
</div>
```